# pointer to constructor to a class in perl6

Tags: class, raku

I am trying to write some classes with Perl 6 just for testing out Perl 6 classes and methods.

Here is the code:

```
class human1 {
    method fn1() {
        print "#from human1.fn1\n";
    }
}

class human2 {
    method fn1() {
          print "#from human2.fn1\n";
    }
}

my $a = human1.new();
my $b = human2.new();

$a.fn1();
$b.fn1();

print "now trying more complex stuff\n";

my $hum1_const = &human1.new;
my $hum2_const = &human2.new;

my $c = $hum2_const();
$c.fn1();
```

Essentially I want to be able to use either the `human1` constructor or `human2` constructor to be able to build `$c` object dynamically. But I'm getting the following error:

```
Error while compiling /usr/bhaskars/code/perl/./a.pl6
Illegally post-declared types:
    human1 used at line 23
    human2 used at line 24
```

How do I create `$c` using the function pointers to choose which constructor I use?

Comment: Try  remove ampersand when declaring `$hum2_const` : `my $hum2_const = human2.new;` and put an ampersand in front of `$hum2_const` and remove the parenthesis when defining `$c`: `my $c = &$hum2_const;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a case of an LTA error.  What I understand you want to achieve, is a lambda that will create a new `human1` or `human2` object for you.  The way you do that is not correct, and the error it causes is confusing.

```
my $hum1_const = -> { human1.new };
my $hum2_const = -> { human2.new };
```

would be a correct way of doing this.  Although, I would consider this a bit of an obfuscation.  Since `human1` and `human2` are already constants, you can assign them to a variable, and then just call `new` on that:

```
my $the_human = $condition ?? human1 !! human2;
my $c = $the_human.new;
$c.fn1;
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4):

To get a “reference” to `.new` you have to use the meta object protocol.
Either [`.^lookup`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/lookup), or [`.^find_method`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/find_method).

```perl6
my $hum1-create = human1.^find_method('new');
```

That is still not quite what you are looking for, as methods require either a class object or an instance, as their first argument.

```perl6
my $c = $hum1-create( human1 );
```

So you would probably want to curry the class as the first argument to the method.

```perl6
my $hum1-create = human1.^find_method('new').assuming(human1);

my $c = $hum1-create();
```

---

Note that [`.assuming`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/assuming) in this case basically does the same thing as

```perl6
-> |capture { human1.^find_method('new').( human1, |capture ) }
```

So you could just write:

```perl6
my $hum1-create = -> |capture { human1.new( |capture ) }
```

Or if you are never going to give it an argument

```perl6
my $hum1-create = -> { human1.new }
```

---

Also you can store it in a `&` sigiled variable, so you can use it as if it were a normal subroutine.

```perl6
my &hum1-create = human1.^find_method('new').assuming(human1);

my $c = hum1-create;
```