# Syntax of the method of an instantiated object: can't seem to get it right

Tags: functional-programming, raku

I want to get a *pointer* to an object method, for instance for this class

```perl6
class Foo { 
    has $thing = "baz"; 
    method bar() { say $thing }
}; 

sub quux( Callable $flimflam ) { 
    $flimflam() 
}; 
my $foo = Foo.new;
```

I want to grab of the `$foo.bar` method pointer to pas it to quux. However, this

```perl6
quux(&($foo.bar))
```

fails with `Type check failed in binding to parameter '$flimflam'; expected Callable but got Bool (Bool::True)␤  in sub quux`

This does not work either

```perl6
quux($foo.bar)
```

maybe because it takes no parameters; however, if we change the definition of `bar` to:

```perl6
 method bar($some ) { say $some ~ $thing }
```

Then the error for the call above becomes `Too few positionals passed; expected 2 arguments but got 1␤  in method bar`, the error creeps up to bar itself, which means the object itself does not get in.

I have [checked out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47994213/pointer-to-constructor-to-a-class-in-perl6), but it's for a class method (new) and it involves using the meta-object protocol. Would there be a simpler way of doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the "static" method with [`.^lookup`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/lookup) (the `^` indicates that it's a call on the meta object).

That method is not bound to the invocant `$foo` in any way, so you have to call it as

```
class Foo { 
    has $thing = "baz"; 
    method bar() { say $thing }
}; 

sub quux( Callable $flimflam ) { 
    $flimflam() 
}; 
my $foo = Foo.new;

my $method_bar = $foo.^lookup('bar');
$method_bar($foo);
```

You can use a closure to bind the method to the invocant:

```
my $bound_method = -> |c { $method_bar($foo, |c) }
```

Perl 6 also has a shortcut built in for that:

```
my $bound_method = $method_bar.assuming($foo);
```

But you can see that you could abbreviate the whole thing as

```
my $callback = { $foo.bar() }
```

or if the method potentially takes more arguments

```
my $callback = -> |c { $foo.bar(|c) }
```