# How can I obtain a pointer to a Grammar token or regex?

Tags: metaprogramming, grammar, raku, mop

This is similar to [this question for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463535/syntax-of-the-method-of-an-instantiated-object-cant-seem-to-get-it-right), except the same procedure does not seem to work for Grammars.

```
grammar TestGrammar {
    token num { \d+ }
}


my $test-grammar = TestGrammar.new();
my $token = $test-grammar.^lookup('num');

say "3" ~~ $token;
```

This returns:

```
Type check failed in binding to parameter '<anon>'; expected TestGrammar but got Match (Match.new(:orig("3")...)
  in regex num at pointer-to-token.raku line 2
  in block <unit> at pointer-to-token.raku line 9
```

This seems to point to the fact that you need binding to a class/grammar, and not a "bare" token. However, it's not clear how to do that. Passing grammar or an instance of it as a parameter returns a different error:

```
Cannot look up attributes in a TestGrammar type object. Did you forget a '.new'?
```

Any idea of why this does not really work?

**Update**: using `^find_method` as indicated [in this question that is referenced from the one above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47994213/pointer-to-constructor-to-a-class-in-perl6) does not work either. Same issue. Using `assuming` does not fix it either.

**Update 2**: I seem to be getting somewhere here:

```
my $token = $test-grammar.^lookup('num').assuming($test-grammar);

say "33" ~~ $token;
```

Does not yield any syntax error, however it returns `False` no matter what.

Comment: What about just using the regex's *name* as the reference? For example, `grammar foo { token bar { . } } my $rule = 'bar'; say foo.parse(:$rule, 9); # ｢9｣`?

Comment: @raiph I was going to answer it myself today in that direction; using `subparse` and not `parse`, but close enough. Why don't you do it yourself so that I can accept it as an answer? Maybe you don't want because it's not exactly what I was asking (still, getting the pointer does not seem to be possible), but it would serve the same purpose.

Comment: I've figured out what I think is a better answer. It doesn't bother with `.parse` or `.subparse`. I don't have time to properly write it up tonight. The very rough version I have right now is `grammar foo { token bar { \d+ } }; my &match = { ($^grammar.^lookup: $^rule)($grammar.new: orig => $^text) }; say '42' ~~ match(foo, 'bar', $_);`. But I want something much closer to your original question and to add explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an argument at the end of your code:

```
grammar TestGrammar {
    token num { \d+ }
}

my $test-grammar = TestGrammar.new();
my $token = $test-grammar.^lookup('num');

say "3" ~~ $token($test-grammar.new: orig => $_);
                 ^^ -- the missing/new bit -- ^^
```

---

I'm confident you can more or less tuck that argument away -- but `.assuming` immediately reifies/evaluates the argument(s) being assumed so that won't work out. Instead we need to postpone that step until the smart match call (to get ahold of the `$_` as it is during the smart match call).

---

We need to change the `$token` declaration and call. Here are two possibilities I can think of:

- **Stick with `$token`**

  Change its declaration, and turn its use with `~~` into a method call:

  ```
  my $token = { $test-grammar.^lookup('num')($test-grammar.new: orig => $_) }

  say "3" ~~ .$token;
             ^ insert dot to make it a method call with `$_` as invocant
  ```
- **Switch to `&token`**

  Now there's no need for the dot in the smart match line. Even better, you can drop the sigil:

  ```
  my &token = { $test-grammar.^lookup('num')($test-grammar.new: orig => $_) }

  say "3" ~~ .&token; # Same as:
  say "3" ~~  &token; # Same as:
  say "3" ~~   token;
  ```

---

A proper answer to your question should really provide a decent answer to these three questions:

- Why does one have to pass a new grammar object?
- What's this `orig` business?
- How could anyone have known this?

I'm not going to answer those questions, at least not adequately/tonight, and perhaps never. (I recall investigating this years ago and getting bogged down in Rakudo code.)

From memory, my working hypothesis boils down:

- There's a fundamental aspect of the regex/grammar machinery wherein it presumes a match/grammar object is setup at the start (and then passed along to subrules as matching happens).
- There's a difference between a method/rule declared with `my` vs with `has` regarding how that happens. (Presumably what `self` is bound to.)
- That difference means user code has to deal with this disparity in the scenario covered by your question.