# How to implement around in Raku

Tags: oop, raku

In Perl, using `Moo`, you can implement `around` subs, which will wrap around other methods in a class.

```
around INSERT => sub {
    my $orig = shift;
    my $self = shift;

    print "Before the original sub\n";
    my $rv  = $orig->($self, @_);
    print "After the original sub\n";
};
```

How can this behaviour be implemented in [Raku](https://raku.org), preferably using a [`role`](https://docs.raku.org/language/objects#index-entry-declarator_role-Roles)?

Answer (score 8):

You can shadow the method with the role and then use `callwith`:

```
class Foo {
    method meth { say 2 }
}

my $foo = Foo.new but role :: {
    method meth(|c) { say 1; callwith(|c); say 3 }
};

$foo.meth
```

Answer (score 8):

**[Method::Modifiers](https://github.com/supernovus/perl6-method-modifiers)**

*Implements before(), after() and around() functions that can be used to modify class methods similarly to Perl 5's Moose. It uses wrap() internally, and returns the wrapper handler, so it is easy to .restore() the original.*

This is how the module implements `around`:

```
sub around ($class, $method-name, &closure) is export
{
  $class.^find_method($method-name).wrap(method { closure(); });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`wrap`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Routine#method_wrap)

```
sub bar () { return "baþ" };

my $wrapped = &bar.wrap( { " → " ~ callsame() ~ " ← " } );

say bar(); # OUTPUT:  «→ baþ ← »
```

Since methods are routines, you'll need a slightly more convoluted way to get a handle on the method itself, but other than that, the method is exactly the same, since [`Method`s](https://docs.raku.org/type/Method) are a subclass of [`Routine`s](https://docs.raku.org/type/Routine)

```
class Baz {
    method bar () { return "baþ" };
}

my &method_bar = Baz.^find_method("bar");
my $wrapped = &method_bar.wrap( { " → " ~ callsame() ~ " ← " } );

say Baz.bar(); # OUTPUT:  «→ baþ ← »
```

The `$wrapped` is a handle that can be used, later on, to unwrap it if needed.

**Edit**: to add the code to get a handle on the class method, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48000368/891440), for instance.

Comment: Wrap doesn't wrap methods

Comment: @ugexe the OP refers explicitly to subs. Also, you can just use that for methods, since it's a [`Method` is a `Routine`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Method)

Comment: I think you're confused. The question itself states 'wrap around other methods in a class.'. `Moo`s around is nothing like wrapping a subroutine.

Comment: @ugexe same difference. Methods are Routines, as I said after the edit.