# How do I take a reference to new?

Tags: raku, higher-order-functions

Suppose I have the following code:

```
my constant @suits = <Clubs Hearts Spades Diamonds>;
my constant @values = 2..14;

class Card {
    has $.suit;
    has $.value;

    # order is mnemonic of "$value of $suit", i.e. "3 of Clubs"
    multi method new($value, $suit) {
        return self.bless(:$suit, :$value);
    }
}
```

It defines some suits and some values and what it means to be a card.

Now, to build a deck, I essentially need to take the cross product of the suits and the values and apply that to the constructor.

The naiive approach to do this, would of course be to just iterate with a loop:

```
my @deck = gather for @values X @suits -> ($v, $c) {
    take Card.new($v, $c);
}
```

But this is Raku, we have [a `cross` function that can take a function as an optional argument!](https://docs.raku.org/type/Array#(List)_routine_cross), so of course I'm gonna do that!

```
my @deck = cross(@values, @suits, :with(Card.new));
# Unexpected named argument 'with' passed
# in block <unit> at .\example.raku line 36
```

... wait no.
What about this?

```
my @deck = cross(@values, @suits):with(Card.new);
# Unexpected named argument 'with' passed
# in block <unit> at .\example.raku line 36
```

Still nothing. Reference maybe?

```
my @deck = cross(@values, @suits):with(&Card.new);
# ===SORRY!=== Error while compiling D:\Code\Raku/.\example.raku
# Illegally post-declared type:
#    Card used at line 36
```

I read somewhere I can turn a function into an infix operator with `[]`

```
my @deck = cross(@values, @suits):with([Card.new]);
# Unexpected named argument 'with' passed
# in block <unit> at .\example.raku line 36
```

That also doesn't work.

If classes are supposed to just be modules, shouldn't I then be able to pass a function reference?

Also why is it saying 'with' is that's unexpected? If I'm intuiting this right, what it's actually complaining about is the type of the input, rather than the named argument.

Comment: Was kind of answered already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47994213/pointer-to-constructor-to-a-class-in-perl6). It also mentions more general methods to obtain a pointer to a method, which might also help you in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is indeed confusing.

The `:with` parameter expects a Callable.  `Card.new` is *not* a Callable.  If you write it as `:with( { Card.new($^number, $^suit) } )`, it appears to work.

Note that I did not use `$^value, $^suit`, because they order differently alphabetically, so would produce the values in the wrong order.  See [The ^ twigil](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#index-entry-$$CIRCUMFLEX_ACCENT) for more information on that syntax.

The error **is** LTA, [this](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/496e91663c) makes it a *little* bit better.

To get back to your question: you *can* find the code object that corresponds to `Card.new` with `^find_method`.  However, that will not work, as `Card.new` actually expects **3** arguments: the invocant (aka `self`), `$value` and `$suit`.  Whereas the `cross` function will only pass the value and the suit.

Comment: sorry, that `Cards` thing is a typo, I didn't copypaste the code and slipped it in by accident. It's meant to say `Card`

Comment: Regarding `:with( { Card.new($^number, $^suit) } )`, that was basically also the solution I found after enough experimenting. I do find it a bit unintuitive that I can't make `new` a callable the way I would any other routine

Comment: @raiph yeah but notice what the error actually says `Card`, because unlike the code-snippet, I **DID** actually copypaste the error message.

Comment: I see that being a problem without an obvious solution besides redesigning the compiler to be multi-pass

Comment: @ElectricCoffee I just realized the error message isn't because you'd written code mentioning `Card` before it was declared. Instead it's [this](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1965). And given that it's a compile-time error, someone could presumably turn it into valid syntax, at least initially in userland (slang, macro, or slacro), and then one day, if found both popular and without being a trap in some way, then shipped in the standard distro, or perhaps even built in if that was considered wise.

Comment: It certainly seems like it would more naturally fit into what people expect would work.
I mean **I** did.

Comment: A quickie helper -- ugly, unintuitive, error prone, and worse, but illustrating the underlying approach if not the desirable sugar and, perhaps, robustness -- would be `sub prefix:<&> ([$invocant, $method]) { $invocant.^find_method($method).assuming: $invocant }; my @deck = cross @values, @suits, :with(& [Card, 'new']);`. But I imagine a slang could make a nice job of it sugar-wise -- as the ideal, `&Card.new` -- and in all other aspects.

Comment: "I see that being a problem without an obvious solution besides redesigning the compiler to be multi-pass" The *compiler* is multipass. For example, as I noted, it lets one call a sub and then define it later. But for *parsers* written to participate well *in the Raku language braid*, their *primary nature* will *always be* single pass. It's a key part of what makes Raku Rules **Godfood**. Anyhow, once it became clear the "Illegally post-declared type" error you got wasn't due to you wanting to refer to a type before it was declared, my point about the compiler fixing that up became moot.

Comment: I would disagree with the compiler being multi-pass: it only passes through the code once and compiles nouns to be subroutine calls, and keeps a list of subs not defined yet.  Then at the end of compilation, issues errors for subs that were not defined.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Yes about subs. But isn't the compiler multi-pass? What am I wrong about in the following? After parsing's done there's an AST. It's then optimized. Then that's turned into bytecode, which is optimized again, etc. Also, backing up to the parser, it's constructed so a `TOP` method could do whatever it wanted in terms of passing over the entire AST as many times as it wishes at the end. This isn't appropriate for Raku braid langs, but Raku could be used as a compiler for non-braid langs, like Andrew's, and then even the parser single-pass pragmatic requirement disappears. No?

Comment: Indeed, a TOP method can do what it wants.  But that doesn't mean it is multi-pass in my mind.  But maybe my mind is too stuck in what multi-pass means or does not mean :-)

Answer (score 4):

The title of your question is “*How do I take a reference to new?*”, but that is not really what you want to do.

Raku being Raku, you can actually get a reference to `new`.

```raku
my $ref = Card.^lookup('new');
```

You can't use it like you want to though.

```raku
$ref(2,'Clubs'); # ERROR
```

The problem is that methods take a class or instance as the first argument.

```raku
$ref(Card, 2,'Clubs');
```

You could use `.assuming` to add it in.

```raku
$ref .= assuming(Card);
$ref(2,'Clubs');
```

But that isn't really any better than creating a block lambda

```raku
$ref = { Card.new( |@_ ) }
$ref(2,'Clubs');
```

---

All of these work:

```raku
cross( @values, @suits ) :with({Card.new(|@_)})   # adverb outside
cross( @values, @suits,  :with({Card.new(|@_)}) ) # inside at end
cross( :with({Card.new(|@_)}), @values, @suits )  # inside at beginning


@values X[&( {Card.new(|@_)} )] @suits # cross meta-op with fake infix op


do {
    sub new-card ($value,$suit) { Card.new(:$value,:$suit) }
    @values X[&new-card] @suits
}

do {
    sub with ($value,$suit) { Card.new(:$value,:$suit) }
    cross(@values,@suits):&with
}
```